# php 5.3 CLI junk characters

Tags: php, character, command-line-interface

I am facing problem like whenever I run a simple php script from the command line, it is showing some junk character before it.

I am using php 5.3.9 on wamp server on windows 7.

Here is my code of my script

```
<?php
echo "Hi"; exit;
?>
```

and here is what i get in cli

```
∩╗┐Hi
```

Let me know if anyone else has faced same like problem and know the solution.

Thanks

Comment: You've saved the file with a BOM marker?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the UTF-8 BOM. In your editor, save the file as 'UTF-8 without BOM' (look for that setting, it must be there somewhere. If you can't find it, change your editor).