# Strange characters in php cli output

Tags: php, laravel, cmd, composer-php

Some strange character are outputted at the beginning of some php console commands.

Running `composer` the output is ok, but laravel `artisan` or `phpunit` outputs `´╗┐`.

[image: Example]

I've tried to encode artisan and phpunit files to UTF-8 without BOM like suggested in [php 5.3 CLI junk characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13798455/php-5-3-cli-junk-characters/13798477#13798477), but that was not the problem.

I'm using ConEmu v131215 on Windows XP x64 and PHP 5.4.24

**Question:** Where can I possibly find the file that outputs the strange characters that show up at the start of every PHP command line program?

Even in windows console this problem happen, not only in ConEmu.

Installing a fresh php 5.3 with default php.ini produces the same result

[image: PHP 5.3 output]

Comment: I wonder why people closed this question, because it is pretty clear to me, but to make things more obvious, I added the question at the bottom.

Comment: I believe, the problem is not related to ConEmu. What happens, if you run your commands in standard Windows console? And, if you run them in ConEmu, but disable "ANSI X3.64" option on the Settings\Features ConEmu page? Also, in is interesting, what exact command are running during execution. May be PHP creates temporarily files with BOM. You can monitor process starts with ProcessMonitor or within ConEmu Settings\Debug\Shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An old vendor lib from FusionCharts encoded as UTF-8 with BOM was the problem.

This file was loaded in my `composer.json` using [autoload files](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#files) from composer, so every time I used `vendor\autoload.php` this file with BOM produced that weird char.

Comment: Um, what was that vendor lib file? It would be extremely useful to know.